# Connected App for Salesforce Community

Tags: connected-apps

We have an external training website we want to use SSO for our community users.  It is simply going to be a link we created at the bottom of the screen that links to the training website.  Can you just use a connected app for this or is there some other configuration we need to do.  Also when creating the connected app, so we can add the information to our training website, is it the my domain for the salesforce org or would it be the community website.